# how do i change camera shortcut

Tags: camera

I updated to blender 2.79 the other day but it got rid of some of my presets. How do I make the camera shortcut to 0, not the num pad 0? I did it before but I forget. 
I know how to change it but when I do it I hit save startup file, but when I open a new file its back to the default.

do I have to do it in user preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your preferences under input enable "emulate numpad". Save your preferences, not your startup file.